# Creating a new column filled with random numbers

Tags: r

I'd like to create a new column in my data frame and fill it with random numbers between 1 to 100 (can repeat).

Below is the code I'm currently using,

```
data$newrow <- rep(1:100,replace=T, nrow(data))
```

I receive this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newrow", value = c(1L, 2L,  :
> replacement has 2088800 rows, data has 20888`

Can you help me fix my code?

Comment: data$newrow <- sample(1:100,replace=T, nrow(data))

Comment: You seem to be mixing up functions. `rep` is in no way random, and it doesn't have those arguments you're using. You're most likely looking for `sample ` or `runif` .

Comment: You need to use `set.seed(1)` for reproducibility.

Comment: I would suggest calling a new column $newcol rather than $newrow

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
data$newrow <- sample(100, size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work, sorry for late reply

```
dataFrame$newcol<-sample(100, size = nrow(dataFrame), replace = TRUE)
```